# WebLogic - JDBC datasource through JNDI causes null PreparedStatement to be returned from weblogic.jdbc.rm.SerialConnection.prepareStatement(String)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, datasource

Hello and thank you for helping!

I am using Weblogic 10.3.0.0 with a JDBC data source configured to use the thin driver from oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver. The driver library is ojdbc6.jar and the driver version is 11.1.0.6.0-Production. On my local client, I was using the 11.2.0.3.0 version but I have also tried the same version as the server but to no avail.

The symptom of the problem comes in the form of two NullPointerExceptions:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getCachedWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:44)
at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:195)
at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.getWrapperClass(WrapperFactory.java:183)
at weblogic.utils.wrapper.WrapperFactory.createWrapper(WrapperFactory.java:168)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:186)
at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.PreparedStatementStub.readResolve(PreparedStatementStub.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1104)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1805)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:197)
at weblogic.rjvm.MsgAbbrevInputStream.readObject(MsgAbbrevInputStream.java:564)
at weblogic.utils.io.ChunkedObjectInputStream.readObject(ChunkedObjectInputStream.java:193)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.ObjectIO.readObject(ObjectIO.java:62)
at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:240)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:223)
at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.internal.ConnectionImpl_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_PoolConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_T4CConnection_1030_WLStub.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialConnection.prepareStatement(SerialConnection.java:228)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1573)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.type.StringType.set(StringType.java:49)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:154)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:61)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:514)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1589)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:67)
```

I have stepped through everything up until weblogic.jdbc.rmi.SerialConnection.prepareStatement since that source is not public. The problem appears to be that this returns a null PreparedStatement which is then passed on to those two methods that throw the NPE.

The datasource is declared as a Spring bean (URL and credentials have been removed for security):

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jdbc/DS</value>
    </property>
    <property name="resourceRef">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://000.00.00.000:15031/</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">principal</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">credentials</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have also set up the same exact data source in the JNDI tree of a locally run WebLogic instance and that works fine with no exceptions. (It might be important to note that my local WebLogic version is 10.3.2):

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jdbc/DS</value>
    </property>
    <property name="resourceRef">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">t3://localhost:7001/</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">principal</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">credentials</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Lastly, by declaring the datasource directly in a Spring bean without referencing JNDI, I also got it to work just fine:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@username.com.com:1530:service_name" />
</bean>
```

Any help is appreciated and I am more than happy to provide any more details if necessary. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I am facing the same issue via Junit code.Do you remember if you were able to resolve this ? (6 years ago ?) Thanks in advance.